# Problem installing kismet

Tags: command-line, 16.04, configuration

I'm having a problem installing `kismet`.
My command was:

```
sudo apt-get install kismet
```

Everything goes fine, but I don't know how to proceed for the configuration.
I click OK, nothing happens...
Can somebody help ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The terminal isn't "clickable" :)

You need to press TAB then use the arrow keys to navigate the options and Enter to confirm. If there are multiple selections followed by an OK/Next or Back/Cancel you need to navigate to and select with Space the intended option from the list then navigate to the aforementioned "buttons" and confirm.

Additional info: [Kismet - The Easy Tutorial - Configurations](http://openmaniak.com/kismet_conf.php)